# Scraping page script suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, web-scraping

I just recently dusted off a script i wrote a good few months ago to get some basic data from Amazon (i have access to the API now so don't need this) but it's bothering me why i can't see the error in the script.

```
<?php

# Example URLs:
# https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=22+Bdc+Scope&ref=nb_sb_noss
# https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Angled+Ceiling+Speaker&ref=nb_sb_noss

$url  = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Angled+Ceiling+Speaker&ref=nb_sb_noss";       
$html = file_get_contents($url);    

echo parseHtmlAmazonScraper($html);

function parseHtmlAmazonScraper($html) {
    try {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
        $nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-4-of-36 sg-col-4-of-28 sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col sg-col-4-of-20 sg-col-4-of-32']");
        if (sizeof($nodeList) == 0) {
            $nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='sg-col-4-of-12 sg-col-8-of-16 sg-col-16-of-24 sg-col-12-of-20 sg-col-24-of-32 sg-col sg-col-28-of-36 sg-col-20-of-28']");
        }
        $res = [];

        foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
            $new = new DomDocument;
            $new->appendChild($new->importNode($node, true));
            $N = new DomXPath($new);            
            $nodeImg  = $N->query("//img[@class='s-image']")->item(0);          
            $Img      = $nodeImg->getAttribute('src');          
            $nodeLink = $N->query("//a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']")->item(0);
            $Path     = $nodeLink->getAttribute('href');
            $Name     = trim($nodeLink->textContent);       
            $res[] = [
                'productLink' => $Path,
                'productDescription' => $Name,
                'productImage' => $Img
            ];
        }
        return $res;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();      
    }
}

?>
```

It worked well when testing a few months ago, when i check the HTML structure i can't see anything obvious has changed, what i'm getting is:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null**

So i'm basically getting **null** back from the `$nodeList` when i do a `var_dump()` i get:

```
object(DOMNodeList)[47]
  public 'length' => int 44
```

The HTML structure of the test page seems fine to me, is there something obvious i am missing here?

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated, i usually like to understand why things break.

Comment: One of the problems with scraping data is that the page structure can easily change, it's a very fragile method (especially with fast moving and complicated page structures).  You could spend some time trying to understand why - but IMHO you would be better of just moving onto something new.

Comment: _"So i'm basically getting null back from the $nodeList"_ ...I'm unsure how this is relevant? It also seems to be contradicted by the var_dump output. The error is not focused there. In the code shown, there are two calls to `getAttribute()`, on `$nodeImg` and `$nodeLink`, but not on `$nodeList`. You didn't say which of those caused the error, but if one of them is null, then it follows that the code which populated them (a call to `$N->query` in each case) failed to find anything. Presumably this means the selectors are incorrect, or the HTML has changed and doesn't contain what you expected.

Comment: This is strictly speaking, not an error in the script. There simply appears to be a node without an image or a link. If your protect your code against that it will probably run fine.